# How to get dynamic html-table-content

Tags: php, html

This is the output of one of my file

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td> Description 1 </td>  <td> Content 1 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> Description 2 </td>  <td> Content 2 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> Description 3 </td>  <td> Content 3 </td>
</tr>
```

I want to get the content of Description x with php and then I want to read out the Content x. One of my problem is, that before grapping the content I don't know how many description-td's I have.

Should DOM / getElementsBy ... work for my problem?

Best regards,
Susan

Comment: It depends if you want to do this on server-side (PHP) or client-side (JavaScript), but, yes, it should -- but this is a very general answer to a very general question.

Comment: I will do it on server-side. Yeah I just need an general answer. I want to know how to do this most effectly :)

Comment: You can do this in simple for or foreach loops. Just `echo` each row in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a solution with JQUERY. [Try if yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/TLT4P/)
In this example we show in an alert dialog the content of the description number 3.

HTML:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td> Description 1 </td>  <td> Content 1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Description 2 </td>  <td> Content 2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Description 3 </td>  <td> Content 3 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JQUERY:

```
// Search content of description number 3
$(document).ready(extractContent(3));

function extractContent(num) {

    $('td', $('#mytable')).each(function() {
       // The text in the first column must match " Description num "
       if ($(this).text() == " Description " + num + " ")
           alert("Content found: "+$(this).next().text());
    });
}
```